# Check for duplicate values in listbox and give error message

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to prevent from entering duplicate values in ListBox by giving an error message saying value has been duplicated in c#.

E.g.

```
Listbox 
Red|Blue|Red
```

Error: duplicate values has been entered.

Comment: Please post your code. The list box the data source you have etc.

Comment: private void CheckForListBOx(string ctrlParam, string[] values, string listDetailForErrorMessage)
        {
            values = ctrlParam.Split('|');

            foreach (string value in values)
            { if(ctrlParam.Contains(value))

Comment: Dear OP, you have edit option

Answer (score 0):

using linq: if list is string array,

```
if(myArray.Distinct().Count() < myArray.Length)
{
 // Show error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if (!ListBox1.Items.Contains(ListBox1.Items.FindByText(item)))
{    
    ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
else
{
  Response.Write(@"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert('Duplicate value hadbeen entered')</SCRIPT>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Item in List box if item does not exits in ListBox then add otherwise not.

as per your requirement you can find item in ListBox by using [FindByValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [FindByText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
ListItem item = ListBox1.Items.FindByValue(value);
if (item == null)
{
     item.Add(value);
}
else
{
// Display message to user. Item already exists in listbox
}
```